how to prevent spring deps excluding in io.quarkus:quarkus-spring-di
I use quarkus quarkus-spring-di in my project.
In it's POM file https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/quarkus/quarkus-spring-di/3.16.1/quarkus-spring-di-3.16.1.pom quarkus exludes artifacts
<excludedArtifact>org.springframework:spring-core</excludedArtifact>
<excludedArtifact>org.springframework:spring-beans</excludedArtifact>
<excludedArtifact>org.springframework:spring-context</excludedArtifact>

Doing this quarkus excludes this dependencies from runtime (quarkus-app-dependencies.txt).
But I need these deps in runtime. How can i add them to runtime context of quarkus app?

In your pom.xml -> coordinate quarkus-spring-di, can you try adding exclusions for spring-core, spring-beans, and spring-context and add them manually.

@SharadPaul https://quarkus.io/guides/class-loading-reference#banned-dependencies  In pom the exclusion is handled by the quarkus-extension-maven-plugin, then i have these dependencies in compile time. Quarkus just eliminates them from it's runtime. Thank you for the advice, but it doesn't help to force quarkus to add these deps to runtime (quarkus-app-dependencies.txt) and i got java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for some of my classes initialization when run application. On build time i have no any troubles.

That sounds very core, why don't you use spring boot ? or why do you use quarkus ?

@ozkanpakdil i am in process of migration from spring-boot to quarkus. But i am not able to rewrite everything right away.
